# Using counter in csdef

Tags: macros, counters, etoolbox

I'm trying to implement a map:
counter => string + another_counter:

1 => eq1

2 => eq2

3 => ineq1
...

I use `\csdef` like this:

```
\csdef{probName\thecntProblem}{\csuse{filePrefix}\arabic{cntLocalProblem}}%
```

but `cntLocalProblem` always points to its last value. I understand that `\csuse` just inserts the text saved in `\csdef`s key. But how do I substitute `cntLocalProblem` with its actual value?

Thank you.

Comment: You should probably mention that `\csdef` and friends are defined by the `etoolbox` package

Comment: did you try `\csedef`?

Comment: `\thecntProblem` might not be what you want, I think it's prefereable to have `\arabic{cntProblem}` instead.

Comment: There is no point in using `\csuse{filePrefix}` instead of the simpler `\filePrefix`

Comment: @OrdevAgens: What is your use-case here? One can use references to define commands as well, allowing you to use them anywhere in your document (before or after they're defined).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\csdef` etc. does infact allow numbers in 'command' names, but here's another way using `\@nameuse` and `\@namedef` from LaTeX2e core with expansion of the counter values -- I don't think that `etoolbox` is needed here for such an approach!

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{cntLocalProblem}
\newcounter{cntProblem}
\newcommand{\fileprefix}{foo}




\makeatletter
\def\localprobname#1{%
  \@namedef{probName\thecntProblem}{\expandafter\fileprefix#1}
}
\newcommand{\defineprobname}{%
  \expandafter\localprobname\expandafter{\number\value{cntLocalProblem}}
}
\newcommand{\getprobname}[1]{%
  \@nameuse{probName#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\setcounter{cntProblem}{10}

\setcounter{cntLocalProblem}{15}

\defineprobname


\setcounter{cntProblem}{20}

\setcounter{cntLocalProblem}{115}

\defineprobname


\getprobname{10}

\getprobname{20}

\getprobname{40}% should be undefined -> no output
\hrule

\end{document}
```